# Visual Studio 2010 takes forever to link when using too many string literals

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, linker

I'm using visual studio 2010 to build a small project which declares a vector and does push_back for close to 1500 records, which has 6 string member variables. An instance of Employee is created by passing string literals hard coded in the cpp file.

sample code:

```
struct Employee{

Employee(string && name, string && id, string && ssn, string && location, string && phone): name(move(name)), id(move(id)), ssn(move(ssn)), location(move(location)), phone(move(phone)){}

string name;
string id;
string ssn;
string location;
string phone;
};

int main (int argc, char *args[]){
vector<Employee> ec;
ec.push_back(Employee(string("Sam"), string("sam"), string("215559999"), string("Seattle"), string("2145482058")));
ec.push_back(Employee(string("Adams"), string("ada"), string("124558888"), string("Pittsburgh"), string("6545482058")));
/*push_back 1500 records*/
}
```

This code compiles and links fine in debug mode. In release mode, the code compiles just fine, but takes forever to link. Last 2 lines from output console is
     
1>Link:
     
1>  Generating code

PS: Disabling the optimization (properties > C/C++ > Optimization), from a release default  of "Maximize Speed /O2", resolves the issue, but that's not something i would want to consider unless there's really no other way.

EDIT:
File IO is not something we are comfortable with due to the slight delay it adds to process, especially because this code will be kicked off in 100s of jobs at once. So given this is a 30x4000 static table, we narrowed down on having a in-memory table, and avoiding loading delays due to io. Hard-coded definitely makes the code look more like a text file, but we are looking for performance.
So, is there any way for Visual studio to accept hard coding of string literals, and linking them fast. If not, i'll go back to my file io approach.

Comment: You have a main method with 1500 `push_back` lines of code!? Move that to a separate file and read it at runtime.

Comment: There's a pragma that allows you to disable optimisations around a function. Not sure if it works with link time code generation though (which you're using).

Comment: @luiscubal The method which does the push_back is a member function of a singleton class. I had put this entire thing in main to make sure it's purely because of string literals. File io, is definitely fall back for me now. But before going ahead with file io, wanted to check if there's something i should try/know

Comment: @AlanStokes Didnt know of such pragma. Will look for that. Thanks!

Comment: Not the kind of code that you'd expect to be verified for link performance.  This sounds like a /LTCG pessimization, it is turned on by default.  Just turn it off, Linker + Optimization property page.

Comment: "Link" followed by "generating code" is a telltale sign of LTCG - it's after all Link Time Code Generation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your literals are all literals, I'd stick with just `const char*` members. All those constructors being called at startup, all calling `strlen` can't be efficient. This also eliminates 12.000 temporaries, which is going to be a relief for the compiler.

Also, call `reserve` on that vector.

[edit]
A common technique to avoid calling `strlen` at startup is to pass the strings as `const char (&str)[N]` and use Template Argument Deduction to get the string length N. In this particular case, the compiler is already suffering (28 minutes) so adding templates may very well make it worse. You'd have to profile it with the actual compiler. In particular, you may want a wrapper to prevent `Employee::Employee` from being instantiated for every possible combination of string lengths.

```
template<size_t N> inline std::string make_string(const char (&str)[N])
{
   return std::string(static_cas<const char*>(str), N);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That did the trick. I just changed constructor to take 'const char *' so i cud eliminate temporary string objs, and now my linker is being very reasonable. Linking time came down from 28min, to 17secs
I want to upvote your answer but i dont have enough credits for upvote